# Should I use "it" or “one” in “...living in {it/one} is more uncomfortable...”?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

Here is the context:

> I looked it up to see what it feels like to live in **a castle**. It seems like living in **it** is more uncomfortable than I thought. Firstly, castles aren't designed for dwelling purposes--they are fortresses to fend off enemies.

"It seems like living in **it** is more uncomfortable than I thought."
In this sentence, can I use "**it**" to refer to a castle that I mentioned before?
Or, do I need to use "**one**" because it's not specific enough?

Comment: i would definitely use one as opposed to it, though I can't explain why

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I need a clear explanation.

Comment: You would say _living in it_ if you were talking about a particular castle, but your sentence seems to say that _any_ castle would be uncomfortable to live in (unless you mentioned one earlier). (BTW Even fortresses had living accommodation!)

Comment: You're already straying from "100% natural" use of pronouns with that initial *I looked **it** up...* Because of [redundant?] ***to see***, it would be clunky to simply remove that first pronoun, but *I looked up what it feels like...* might be more natural phrasing. Plus you could avoid having so many potentially confusing *different* referents for ***it*** by changing ***It seems*** to something like ***Apparently***. But that's really "writing advice", which is probably Off Topic.

Comment: @KateBunting Are you saying that I need to use "one" instead of "it" in that sentence?

I have another question.

"they are fortresses to fend off enemies."
In this sentence, do I need to change "they" to "castles" because I'm not talking about particular castles?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I corrected what I wrote.
I wanted to know what living in a castle feels like, so I searched on Google. Apparently living in one is more uncomfortable than I thought. Firstly, castles aren't designed for dwelling purposes--they are fortresses to fend off enemies.

Does this sound better?

Comment: You could also say _Living in one **would be** more uncomfortable than I thought_, as you are only imagining what it would be like. It's fine to use _they_ to make a general statement about castles.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks. "They" can be used to make a general statement. How about "**we**" as in "**We** need to tackle global warming by reducing waste"? Can "**we**" be used to make a general statement as well?

Comment: Yes, _we_ can mean 'humanity in general' - but that's a different topic.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks a lot. Have a good day.

Comment: It's stylistically preferable to use ***one*** rather than highlighted ***it*** in the cited text, because preceding ***a castle*** doesn't refer to any *specific* castle. But as I already commented, to my mind the more noticeable "non-idiomatic" element is that *first* occurrence of the pronoun in initial *I looked **it** up to see [what something was]*. It may be just me, but I really don't like *that* pronoun being used as a "forward reference". But I have no problem with *I wanted to know [what something was] so I looked it up* (where ***it*** refers *back* to a preceding "noun phrase").

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like living in **it** is more uncomfortable than I thought.

Here *it* doesn't have a proper antecedent. The first sentence says "***a** castle*, so there isn't any specific castle for *it* to refer to. It would be better to use "*one*", which in effect selects an arbitrary single instance of "*a castle*".

> It seems like living in **one** is more uncomfortable than I thought.

Comment: One paragraph of this answers the OP's question: "*Here it doesn't have a proper antecedent. The first sentence says "a castle, so there isn't any specific castle for it to refer to. It would be better to use "one", which in effect selects an arbitrary single instance of "a castle".*". They didn't ask for a complete breakdown and analysis of the entire sentence, so the rest of this answer is off-topic and I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

- "it" refers to the specific thing.
- "one" refers to one of those things.

Another way to think of it:

- If you say "the," use "it."
- If you say "a/an," use "one."

So since you said "...a castle..." say "...living in one..."
*See* [the difference between words: it and one, them and ones](https://englishhelponline.me/2010/12/13/the-difference-between-words-it-and-one-them-and-ones/#:%7E:text=Recently%20there%20have%20been%20a,the%20pronoun%20is%20%E2%80%9Cone%E2%80%9D.).

Comment: This isn't quite right. It's very normal for something to be referred to with "a ___" on first reference and "it" on later reference; consider e.g. "He drove a fancy car. It was big, and bright red, and it had a sunroof, which he liked even if he almost never opened it."

Comment: @ruakh says "*He drove a fancy car. It was big,*". This example *is* correct, but only because "it" doesn't refer to "a car", but to the specific fancy car that he drove.